Is social psychology on-topic?
I had a question about the Milgram Experiment which is a cornerstone of social psychology. I did a search and was surprised to find no previous questions on the topic. Hence, my question.
Is social psychology on-topic? 

Yes, as is mentioned in help.

If you have questions about ...
Cognitive science Psychology (e.g., cognitive, social, developmental,
  biological, applied, clinical, organizational, etc.) Psychiatry
  Neuroscience and neurobiology ... then you're in the right place to
  ask your question.

We even have a tag for it: social-psychology.
Your question is more than welcome. ;p

Oh! I got hung up on Milgrim that I didnt even think there could be a social psychology tag. Sorry for the unnecessary question!

No problem @AsheeshR! We're still in beta so any question on Meta about our scope is fine.
